# Big numbers in google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I use google form to populate some informations about banks. One of the field in form is 20-digit string (30101810100000000777 for example). But when it stores in google sheet it become a different value - 3,01018E+19 and in this case I loose part of information. 
Changing column format to text does not have an effect. 
Who knows is it any simple way to fix this problem? 
Because I see only one way - to write script which will fill the sheet in different way. I mean scirpt on form side trigger onFormSubmit.

Answer (score 1):

The number is still there. If you click on the cell you will see the longer number. The spreadsheet just converts it to exponential notation to make it easier to read. No data is lost.